# SwiftUI How to Create a button that adds an item to a list that contains a navigation link

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I've never done a post on this before, so hopefully this is set up correctly.

I'm new to swift, and I want to create a button that adds a new item to a list that contains a navigation link to a file that it would create with linked data from the previous item, and I haven't found any way to do this after spending a few days on research and testing.

This is what my app currently looks like for the layout I want in the end: [Q1](https://gyazo.com/57250ce4ec7b6e13975c31454e2dfdff) , and here is a preview of the different Q1-4 Views I mentioned: [Q1-4](https://gyazo.com/dd2a11953d0fe2db549695ff64d63512)

I know it's a lot, so let me explain more in depth: I want to have a list contained in what is called 'Q1' (as seen above) that starts out with 'Week 1', and as you click the add button, I want it to add a 'Week 2' and so forth up to 10 weeks. Once you hit 10 weeks, I want the user to have to change to the different view, 'Q2', which then they can add Week 11-20, and so forth until Q4, which limits it to a total of 40 Weeks. I want each week to contain a navigation link to a new view; however, I also want data from the previous week to be carried over as soon as I create the new week, so the user won't have to manually put in the previous week's data.

I know how to do some of this by using a JSON file for the numbers, as I've seen tutorials on that, however, I don't see a point to this, as the only data I need for the Week numbers are 1-40, but I can't seem to get it to work with an array or anything. I do know that I can use an @EnvironmentObject to get the data I need from the other pages, but I'm not exactly sure how to set that up either. Other than that, I'm stuck! Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct BillsView: View {

    @State private var quarterNumber = 0

    let quarterNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
               Section {
                    Picker("Quarter Number", selection: $quarterNumber) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< quarterNumbers.count) {
                            Text("Q\(self.quarterNumbers[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    if quarterNumber == 0 {
                        Q1View()
                    } else if quarterNumber == 1 {
                        Q2View()
                    } else if quarterNumber == 2 {
                        Q3View()
                    } else if quarterNumber == 3 {
                        Q4View()
                    }
                }
            Spacer()
            }

            .navigationBarTitle("Bills")
            .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton(),
            trailing: Button(action: {
                //Adds the new week
            }){
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
            })

        }
    }
}

struct Q1View: View {

    @State private var weekNumber = 0

    let weekNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink(destination: Week1View()) {
                Text("Week 1")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Week1View: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            link(label: "Gross Income", destination: GrossIncome())
            link(label: "Expenses", destination: Expenses())
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Week 1"), displayMode: .inline)
    }

    private func link<Destination: View>(label: String, destination: Destination) -> some   View {
        return NavigationLink(destination: destination) {
                Text(label)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure whether i understood you right, but i made a very simple  example which answers the question of your title

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var list : [String] = ["Chris"]
    @State private var quarterNumber = 0

    var body: some View {
        Group () {
            Button(action: {
                self.list.append("whatever")
            }) {
                Text("tap me")
            }
            NavigationView{

                List(list, id: \.self) { item in

                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: View2(text: "hallo")
                            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Categories"), displayMode: .automatic)
                    ) {
                        Text("Categories")
                    }.isDetailLink(false) // damit der Doof nicht rechts das nächste Menu öffnet

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {

    var text : String

    var body: some View {

        Text(text)
    }
}
```